# How do i add one textbox data to another textbox(samedata) while clicking on checkbox using jquery in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Can any one solve my problem?
I want to add one textbox value to another textbox(same value without deleting from first textbox)using jquery in asp.net. I wrote this code but it is not working. My code is below.

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{ 
    $("input#CheckBox1").bind("click", function (o) 
     {  
       if     ($("input#CheckBox1:checked").length) 
         { 
           $("#txtTo").text($("#txtFrom").val()); 
         } 
       else 
       {     $("#txtTo").val(""); 
       } 
     }); 
} );
```

Comment: Can you show your ASP.NET markup? Also, is this script in the same page or in an external file?

Comment: So spin up a console and make sure the element ids you're referencing are actually the ids you think you're referencing. see what the console tells you is going wrong....

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this out, and instead of `$("#txtTo").text($("#txtFrom").val());` try `$("#txtTo").val($("#txtFrom").val());`. That worked when I tried it.

Also, instead of using `bind("click", function()` you could use `.click(function()`

**EDIT:** For instance:

```
$("input#CheckBox1").click(function () 
             {  
               if(this.checked) 
                 { 
                   $("#txtTo").val($("#txtFrom").val()); 
                 } 
               else 
               {     $("#txtTo").val(""); 
               } 
             });
```

Comment: Thanks for you replay ,i tried by using your code but it is not working,can u tell where is the problem in my code. $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#<%= CheckBox1.ClientID %>").bind("click", function (o) {  
    if (this.checked) { 
        $("#<%= txtTo.ClientID %>").text($("#<%= txtFrom.ClientID %>").val()); 
    } 
    else {
        $("#<%= txtTo.ClientID %>").val(""); 
    } 
}); 
    });

Comment: First, I didn't use the `ClientID` thing and got it to work on an asp.net page. Second, in your `if` statement, the first block there, you use `.text()` which you should try switching for `.val()` and that should work.

Comment: Also, be sure you're using the correct `id` for each part. You can check it by running the code and viewing the page source code.

Comment: You're welcome, but to really thank someone on SO, you can vote up their answer/comment or click the check by their answer to select it as the one that helped. Also, don't spam comments to try to get people to help you.